# Convert bit strings to characters

Tags: java

```
public String convertBinaryToString(String binary){
    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i += 8) {
        int charCode = Integer.parseInt(binary.substring(i,i+7), 2);
        result += new Character((char) charCode).toString();

    }
    // String(binary.getBytes(),0,binary.getBytes().length,"ASCII");
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
//This is my goal but it does not work that way
    for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i+=8) {
                String num = binary.substring(i,i+7);
                char c = (char)Integer.parseInt(num,2);
                result += c;
            }
```

**input** : 0000011010001100101110110011011001101111
**output** : hello //my output : F]7

Comment: What was your *question*?

Comment: The second argument to String.substring is exclusive i.e. it should be i+8.

Comment: i + 8 did not work

Comment: Using `(char)charCode` to convert ASCII to UTF-16 works but isn't very clear. You could back it up with a long explanatory comment on the design of Unicode and its UTF-16 encoding or just use  `StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.newDecoder().decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(asciiBytes)).toString()` This would also give you a very informative exception when your ASCII bytes aren't ASCII bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **UPDATE:**
>
> First of all your input is incorrect!!  At least the first two are not
>   printable.  For "hello" the proper binary representation is:
>
> `01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111`

You can parse a String directly into an Integer via the `Integer.parseInt( String s, int radix )` method, where radix specifies the base of the number you want to parse. Since you want to parse a binary number you should use radix = 2. Then cast it to char.

*Example:*

```
String num = "01000001";                   // char 'A' in binary ( decimal 65 )
int value = Integer.parseInt( num, 2 );    // parses string to int ( 65 )
char character = (char)value;              // parses int (65) to char ('A')
```

or in short:

```
String num = "01000001";
char c = (char) Integer.parseInt(num, 2);
```

Comment: You say I'm looking for a single character, the answers are different
input : 00000110|00011001|01110110|01101100|01101111
output : hello

Comment: ok.. i missunderstood your question. i have updated my answer!

Comment: I want to write all together, not just a single character

Comment: i know.. nevertheless your input is wrong!
it should be:
0110100001100101011011000110110001101111
maybe therefor you get a wrong output.
first change the input an then retry you code.

Answer (score 0):

Interger.parseInt (String nam, int radix) where radix=2 for binary, this is for convert into integer than type cast into char you get your answer.

int x = Integer.parseInt (binary,2);
char c = (char)x;

Comment: I could not understand sorry